# NSCollectionView Drag and Drop with Sections - Swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview

I’ve been working on an app with an `NSCollectionView` that utilizes drag and drop for reordering.  It works great.

I decided to include sections, which I’ve done, and it’s looking great.   This broke my drag and drop code.

I see in the console a message saying:

> 2018-05-04 16:06:26.310605-0700 Sections[95751:18347288] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[NSCollectionView itemAtIndex:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1561.40.112/Binding.subproj/NSCollectionView.m:2284
>   2018-05-04 16:06:26.311075-0700 Sections[95751:18347288] [General] Use
>   -indexPathForItem:, when the CollectionView may contain more than one section

I’ve been searching for an example to learn from, but so far, I haven’t found anything.

Does anyone have an example project or just some advice on how to go about this?

Side note, this project is in Swift 4.  If you have something in Objective-C, I’m sure I could translate the ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Bob

Comment: Do you use `-[NSCollectionView itemAtIndex:]` in your code?

Comment: this is what I am currently using:

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

Comment: Do you call `item(at:)` with an `Int` index on the collection view? It would help us helping you if you post the relevant code in the question. The message says "Assertion failure in -[NSCollectionView itemAtIndex:]. Use -indexPathForItem:" but  I think it should be `itemAtIndexPath:` or `item(at:)` with an `IndexPath`.